# Shop This Collection

Tags: magento2, attributes, product-collection

How can I achieve the following image(shop this collection) in Magento 2 product page by adding an attribute?

[image]

Comment: Means you want a product collection of an attibute

Comment: @AmitBera Yes, I want to show product collection of an attribute.

Answer (score 2):

```
protected $_attributeFactory;

 public function __construct(
    ....
    \Magento\Catalog\Model\ResourceModel\Eav\Attribute $attributeFactory,
    ....
) {
    ....
    $this->_attributeFactory = $attributeFactory;
    ....
}

public function <func_name>()
{
    $attributeInfo = $this->_attributeFactory->getCollection();

   foreach($attributeInfo as $attributes)
   {
        $attributeId = $attributes->getAttributeId();
        // You can get all fields of attribute here
   }
}
```

Comment: please use this code.

Comment: @manesh - how will I show the product collection?

Answer (score 1):

For your requirement, you need to create a view section means [**create block class,phtml, layout file**](https://www.mageplaza.com/magento-2-module-development/view-block-layout-template-magento-2.html) .

***Create a custom Block  on block  class call product collection `\Magento\Catalog\Model\ResourceModel\Product\Collection`  and filter that collection by this attribute value.***

### Block Class:

Assume that Block file  **CustomProducts.php** location: `app/code/{Vendorname}/{ModuleName}/Block/Product/`

```
<?php

namespace {Vendorname}\{ModuleName}\Block\Product;

use Magento\Customer\Model\Context as CustomerContext;

/**
 * New products block
 *
 * @SuppressWarnings(PHPMD.LongVariable)
 */
class CustomProducts extends \Magento\Catalog\Block\Product\AbstractProduct implements
    \Magento\Framework\DataObject\IdentityInterface
{
    /**
     * Default value for products count that will be shown
     */
    const DEFAULT_PRODUCTS_COUNT = 10;

    /**
     * Products count
     *
     * @var int
     */
    protected $_productsCount;

    /**
     * @var \Magento\Framework\App\Http\Context
     */
    protected $httpContext;

    /**
     * Catalog product visibility
     *
     * @var \Magento\Catalog\Model\Product\Visibility
     */
    protected $_catalogProductVisibility;

    /**
     * Product collection factory
     *
     * @var \Magento\Catalog\Model\ResourceModel\Product\CollectionFactory
     */
    protected $_productCollectionFactory;

    /**
     * @param Context $context
     * @param \Magento\Catalog\Model\ResourceModel\Product\CollectionFactory $productCollectionFactory
     * @param \Magento\Catalog\Model\Product\Visibility $catalogProductVisibility
     * @param \Magento\Framework\App\Http\Context $httpContext
     * @param array $data
     */
    public function __construct(
        \Magento\Catalog\Block\Product\Context $context,
        \Magento\Catalog\Model\ResourceModel\Product\CollectionFactory $productCollectionFactory,
        \Magento\Catalog\Model\Product\Visibility $catalogProductVisibility,
        \Magento\Framework\App\Http\Context $httpContext,
        array $data = []
    ) {
        $this->_productCollectionFactory = $productCollectionFactory;
        $this->_catalogProductVisibility = $catalogProductVisibility;
        $this->httpContext = $httpContext;
        parent::__construct(
            $context,
            $data
        );
    }


    /**
     * Prepare and return product collection
     *
     * @return \Magento\Catalog\Model\ResourceModel\Product\Collection|Object|\Magento\Framework\Data\Collection
     */
    protected function _getProductCollection()
    {

        /** @var $collection \Magento\Catalog\Model\ResourceModel\Product\Collection */
        $collection = $this->_productCollectionFactory->create();
        $collection->setVisibility($this->_catalogProductVisibility->getVisibleInCatalogIds());

        $collection = $this->_addProductAttributesAndPrices(
            $collection
        )->addStoreFilter()
        ->addAttributeToFilter('{AttriBute_Code}','{ValueOfFilter}')     // apply your attrbute    
        ->setPageSize(
            $this->getProductsCount()
        )->setCurPage(
            1
        );

        return $collection;
    }

    /**
     * Prepare collection with new products
     *
     * @return \Magento\Framework\View\Element\AbstractBlock
     */
    protected function _beforeToHtml()
    {
        $this->setProductCollection($this->_getProductCollection());
        return parent::_beforeToHtml();
    }

    /**
     * Set how much product should be displayed at once.
     *
     * @param int $count
     * @return $this
     */
    public function setProductsCount($count)
    {
        $this->_productsCount = $count;
        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * Get how much products should be displayed at once.
     *
     * @return int
     */
    public function getProductsCount()
    {
        if (null === $this->_productsCount) {
            $this->_productsCount = self::DEFAULT_PRODUCTS_COUNT;
        }
        return $this->_productsCount;
    }

    /**
     * Return identifiers for produced content
     *
     * @return array
     */
    public function getIdentities()
    {
        return [\Magento\Catalog\Model\Product::CACHE_TAG];
    }
}
```

### templats file .phtml code :

Phtml file `items.phtml` location is location: `app/code/{Vendorname}/{ModuleName}/view/frontend/templates/`

```
/* @var $block \Magento\Catalog\Block\Product\AbstractProduct */
?>

<?php
    $exist = $block->getProductCollection();
    $type = 'shop';
    $mode = 'grid';
    $type = $type . ' ' . $mode;

    $class = 'widget' . ' ' . $type;

    $image = 'new_products_content_widget_grid';
    $title = __('Shop this Collection');
    $items = $exist;

    $showAddTo = true;
    $showCart = true;
    $templateType = \Magento\Catalog\Block\Product\ReviewRendererInterface::SHORT_VIEW;
    $description = ($mode == 'list') ? true : false;
    $canItemsAddToCart = true;
?>

<?php if ($exist):?>


     <div class="block <?= /* @escapeNotVerified */ $class ?>">

    <div class="block-title title">
        <strong id="block-<?= /* @escapeNotVerified */ $class ?>-heading" role="heading" aria-level="2"><?= /* @escapeNotVerified */ $title ?></strong>
    </div>
    <div class="block-content content" aria-labelledby="block-<?= /* @escapeNotVerified */ $class ?>-heading">
        <div class="products wrapper grid products-grid products-<?= /* @escapeNotVerified */ $type ?>">
            <ol class="products list items product-items">
                <?php foreach ($items as $_item): ?>
                <?php $available = ''; ?>
                <?php if (!$_item->isComposite() && $_item->isSaleable() && $type == 'related'): ?>
                    <?php if (!$_item->getRequiredOptions()): ?>
                        <?php $available = 'related-available'; ?>
                    <?php endif; ?>
                <?php endif; ?>
                <?php if ($type == 'related' || $type == 'upsell'): ?>
                    <li class="item product product-item" style="display: none;">
                <?php else: ?>
                    <li class="item product product-item">
                <?php endif; ?>
                <div class="product-item-info <?= /* @escapeNotVerified */ $available ?>">
                    <?= /* @escapeNotVerified */ '<!-- ' . $image . '-->' ?>
                    <a href="<?= /* @escapeNotVerified */ $block->getProductUrl($_item) ?>" class="product photo product-item-photo">
                        <?= $block->getImage($_item, $image)->toHtml() ?>
                    </a>
                    <div class="product details product-item-details">
                        <strong class="product name product-item-name"><a class="product-item-link" title="<?= $block->escapeHtml($_item->getName()) ?>" href="<?= /* @escapeNotVerified */ $block->getProductUrl($_item) ?>">
                            <?= $block->escapeHtml($_item->getName()) ?></a>
                        </strong>

                        <?= /* @escapeNotVerified */ $block->getProductPrice($_item) ?>

                            <?php if ($templateType): ?>
                                <?= $block->getReviewsSummaryHtml($_item, $templateType) ?>
                            <?php endif; ?>

                            <?php if ($canItemsAddToCart && !$_item->isComposite() && $_item->isSaleable() && $type == 'related'): ?>
                                <?php if (!$_item->getRequiredOptions()): ?>
                                    <div class="field choice related">
                                        <input type="checkbox" class="checkbox related" id="related-checkbox<?= /* @escapeNotVerified */ $_item->getId() ?>" name="related_products[]" value="<?= /* @escapeNotVerified */ $_item->getId() ?>" />
                                        <label class="label" for="related-checkbox<?= /* @escapeNotVerified */ $_item->getId() ?>"><span><?= /* @escapeNotVerified */ __('Add to Cart') ?></span></label>
                                    </div>
                                <?php endif; ?>
                            <?php endif; ?>

                            <?php if ($showAddTo || $showCart): ?>
                                <div class="product actions product-item-actions">
                                    <?php if ($showCart): ?>
                                        <div class="actions-primary">
                                            <?php if ($_item->isSaleable()): ?>
                                                <?php if ($_item->getTypeInstance()->hasRequiredOptions($_item)): ?>
                                                    <button class="action tocart primary" data-mage-init='{"redirectUrl": {"url": "<?= /* @escapeNotVerified */ $block->getAddToCartUrl($_item) ?>"}}' type="button" title="<?= /* @escapeNotVerified */ __('Add to Cart') ?>">
                                                        <span><?= /* @escapeNotVerified */ __('Add to Cart') ?></span>
                                                    </button>
                                                <?php else: ?>
                                                    <?php $postDataHelper = $this->helper('Magento\Framework\Data\Helper\PostHelper');
                                                    $postData = $postDataHelper->getPostData($block->getAddToCartUrl($_item), ['product' => $_item->getEntityId()])
                                                    ?>
                                                    <button class="action tocart primary"
                                                            data-post='<?= /* @escapeNotVerified */ $postData ?>'
                                                            type="button" title="<?= /* @escapeNotVerified */ __('Add to Cart') ?>">
                                                        <span><?= /* @escapeNotVerified */ __('Add to Cart') ?></span>
                                                    </button>
                                                <?php endif; ?>
                                            <?php else: ?>
                                                <?php if ($_item->getIsSalable()): ?>
                                                    <div class="stock available"><span><?= /* @escapeNotVerified */ __('In stock') ?></span></div>
                                                <?php else: ?>
                                                    <div class="stock unavailable"><span><?= /* @escapeNotVerified */ __('Out of stock') ?></span></div>
                                                <?php endif; ?>
                                            <?php endif; ?>
                                        </div>
                                    <?php endif; ?>

                                    <?php if ($showAddTo): ?>
                                        <div class="secondary-addto-links actions-secondary" data-role="add-to-links">
                                            <?php if ($addToBlock = $block->getChildBlock('addto')): ?>
                                                <?= $addToBlock->setProduct($_item)->getChildHtml() ?>
                                            <?php endif; ?>
                                        </div>
                                    <?php endif; ?>
                                </div>
                            <?php endif; ?>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </li>
                <?php endforeach ?>
            </ol>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
<?php endif;?>
```

### Call the Block at product details:

Now, you have to render the Block class and phtml file from the layout file.

Create product page layout file `catalog_product_view.xml` at `app/code/{Vendorname}/{ModuleName}/view/frontend/layout/`
 and call the below code:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<page  xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd">
    <body>
        <referenceContainer name="content.aside">
        <block class="Magento\Catalog\Block\Product\ProductList\Related" name="catalog.product.shop.collection" template="{Vendorname}_{ModuleName}::items.phtml">
                <block class="Magento\Catalog\Block\Product\ProductList\Item\Container" name="shop.product.addto" as="addto">
                    <block class="Magento\Catalog\Block\Product\ProductList\Item\AddTo\Compare"
                           name="shop.product.addto.compare" as="compare"
                           template="Magento_Catalog::product/list/addto/compare.phtml"/>
                </block>
            </block>
    </referenceContainer>
    </body>
</page>
```

Comment: Thanks @Amit for the help.